# Suppose that (,) is a complete metric space. Show that there is no open, continuous function :→ℚ

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove this statement. I am new to topology and I think the question has something to do with Baire's category theorem, but I can't figure it out.

I tried to come up with a contradiction. I started with the assumption that (X,d) is complete and there exists an open and continuous function. I was planning to prove that X can be written as a union of countable nowhere dense subsets but couldn't succeed. Would appreciate any help.

I am new to topology and the only thing I know about the Baire Category theorem is that every complete metric space is second countable. An alternative proof is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134551/if-x-is-complete-then-there-is-no-continuous-and-open-fx-to-mathbbq) but I couldn't grasp it.

Thanks...

Comment: To proceed by contradiction, I would start by supposing that such an open and continuous function exists. And try to find a separation for $X$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$X=\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q} f^{-1}(\{q\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{q\})$ is closed for each $q$. By Baire Category Theorem there is a non-empty open set $U$ contained in $f^{-1}(\{q\})$ for some $q$. But then $f(U)$ is a non-empty open set in $\mathbb  Q$ which is contained in $\{q\}$. There is no such open set, so $f$ cannot exist as stated.

Comment: Thanks for your response but is there any alternative solution? Can you give me a hint on solving the problem with some more basic definitions?
I am new to topology and the only thing I know about the Baire Category theorem is that every complete metric space is second countable. An alternative proof is provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134551/if-x-is-complete-then-there-is-no-continuous-and-open-fx-to-mathbbq) but I couldn't grasp it.

Comment: Complete metric spaces need not be second countable. They are of  second category. This means they cannot be expressed as countable unions of closed sets with empty interior. I have just applied this statement of BCT. This answer is simpler than the one in your link, I believe. @KaranSingh

Comment: Oh. I misread my definition. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I would also suggest mentioning the linked question in your question, and say what you said above, that you looked at the linked question but didn't understand and that you wanted a simpler proof (this proof is short and elegant I love it). As it stands right now, the question might get flagged as a duplicate

Comment: Thanks, I've mentioned it.